# How do I used LINQ to retrieve a distinct list of object X from a list of object Y where object X is stored in a list against object Y

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects ("Forms") and each of those objects has it's own nested list of another object ("Subjects").

My Form object looks like this:

```
public class Form 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Subject>? LinkedSubjects { get; set; }
}
```

And my nested Subject object looks like this:

```
public class Subject 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Let's say I return a list of forms, each of which has its own nested list of linked subjects. One form might be linked to subjects with IDs of 1 and 2, another might be linked to subjects with IDs of 2 and 3, etc.

Using LINQ, how do I select the lists of subjects from this list of forms, combine them, and then remove any duplicates to leave me with a list of distinct subjects?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, self-explanatory:

```cs
var distinctSubjects =
   listOfForms
   .SelectMany( x => x.LinkedSubjects ) // list of subjects
   .DistinctBy( x => x.Id ) // or DistinctBy(x => (x.Id, x.Name))
```

Why should you opt for `DistinctBy` instead of using `Distinct`? This choice is influenced by the uncertainty regarding whether the `Subject` memory object in your code is genuinely the same on two forms. If it is indeed the same instance, you can simply utilize `Distinct` without any parameters. However, if it represents a different object with identical values, then employing `DistinctBy` right approach.

**EDITED**:

`@Olivier Jacot-Descombes` fixed my previous answer. Thanks.

Comment: You could use `DistinctBy(x => x.Id)` or `DistinctBy(x => (x.Id, x.Name))` depending on what is considered to be a duplicate. See also: [Enumerable.DistinctBy Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinctby).

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes this is a better approach than mine. Please, post it, I will delete mine